# How to send PDF data to a printer programmatically?

Tags: macos, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, cgpdfcontext, apple-pdfkit

In MacOS, I'm using python to write PDF Service Workflows, and after processing the incoming PDF (manipulating it with PyObjC Quartz APIs), I want to send it back to the print queue and get it printed without any user effort.

Is it possible to send a Graphics Context or PDFKit data directly to the printer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Core Printing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/core_printing?language=objc) APIs. You can use [`PMPrinterPrintWithProvider()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/1461110-pmprinterprintwithprovider?language=objc) for the all-in-one approach, or the functions under [Print Loop Functions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/core_printing?language=objc#1666761) to drive the print loop manually.

I don't know off-hand if those functions are available via the PyObjC bridge.

Comment: That's the one. Thanks. I couldn't find the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using python via the command line, this sounds like a job for the Line Printer Remote [`lpr` command line tool](https://ss64.com/osx/lpr.html).

As in `lpr filename.pdf` or `lpr -P printername filename.pdf`.